# Python - find tube-shape structure, fill holes, and generate binary mask for downstream image processing

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

First time posting here.

I am working on image processing for a bioengineering project, and I am using Python, mostly the Skimage package, to batch process the images we have taken. There are 6 - 8 tubes in each image, where cells flow through. At each time point, we captured normal bright field images, as well as fluorescence images. I am trying to identify the tubes based on the bright field images, separate the tubes from the background and label them. The masked/labeled images will be used for downstream processing for the fluorescence images, where we identify cells and get their shape metrics.

***tl;dr***: Python; skimage; image processing; separate tube-like structures from background in a bright field image.

I will use one example to show what I have done. I wanted to include all the intermediate images, but I do not have any reputation points to post more than two images. So I will show the first and last images.

1. I cropped out the scale bar first and obtained a greyscale image, and here is the resulting image.[bf_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn8L2.png)
2. I used sobel_h filter to find the horizontal edges.

   ```
   bf_sobel = sobel_h(bf_cropped)
   io.imshow(bf_sobel)
   ```
3. I then tried all thresholds and picked out a threshold algorithm that looked good to me (otsu)

   ```
   fig, ax = try_all_threshold(bf_sobel, figsize=(25,20), verbose=False)
   plt.show()
   bf_threshold = threshold_otsu(bf_sobel)
   bf_thresholded = bf_sobel > bf_threshold
   io.imshow(bf_thresholded)
   ```
4. I then applied the closing function and remove_small_objects.

   ```
   bf_closed = closing(bf_thresholded)
   bf_small_removed = remove_small_objects(bf_closed, 50)
   io.imshow(bf_small_removed)
   ```

   [bf_small_removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7piB.png)

This is where I got stuck. I am trying to fill the gaps between the tube edges, and create masks for individual tubes to separate them from the background. Any advice? Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you find a nice solution for that problem?